# CSS Progress Bar Error

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I have been trying to display this CSS code correctly in jsFiddle, but does not seem to be working. I have tried to modify the code with no success.

[Original Code](http://www.cssdeck.com/labs/msy68kth)

[jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/BQ9mF)

Comment: Looks like SASS's HAML based syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You must compile it:

```
<h1>Sexy CSS Loader</h1><div class="bubbles"><span></span><span id="bubble2"></span><span id="bubble3"></span></div>
```

Look on this:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BQ9mF/2/)